# Linear interpolation in numpy quantile()

Tags: python, numpy, quartile

Consider the following code:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [21,22,24,24,26,97]
>>> np.quantile(l, 0.25)
22.5
```

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) says:

> linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.

Could anyone please explain what are `i`, `j` and `fraction` in this example and how we get `22.5`?

Comment: `>>> 22 + (24-22) * .25 --> 22.5` ??

Comment: So, `0.25` is `the fractional part of the index`? How do you get the full index? I thought it's `q*n=0.25*6=1.5`.

Comment: The source is here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3721-L3825 .  and my comment doesn't *work* for `np.quantile(l, 0.33)` - I also tried to relate it to https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/auxillar/quantile.htm .

Comment: The indices are definitely involved - the *xtra* 24 affects the value returned.

Comment: I traced it in the debugger: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3854. It turned out to be `q * (n-1) = 0.25 * 5 = 1.25`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works roughly like this:

```
import numpy as np


def my_quantile(array, q):
    n = len(array)
    index = (n - 1) * q
    if int(index) == index:  # has no fractional part
        return array[index]
    fraction = index - int(index)
    left = int(index)
    right = left + 1
    i, j = array[left], array[right]
    return i + (j - i) * fraction


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [21, 22, 24, 24, 26, 97]
    assert my_quantile(arr, 0.33) == np.quantile(arr, 0.33)
    assert my_quantile(arr, 0.25) == np.quantile(arr, 0.25)
    assert my_quantile(arr, 0.75) == np.quantile(arr, 0.75)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very nice solution, but fails. To correct it :

- take return array[int(index)] instead of return array[index] when there is no fractional part
- sort the array at the beginning :) array = np.sort(array) at the beginning

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer will be much better if you put the updated code marking the changed fragments. Otherwise it's harder to follow.